# Как обойтись без вложенных запросов

Tags: sql

Подскажите пожалуйста, как обойтись без вложенных запросов, и посоветуйте парочку манов, если не сложно.

```
SELECT * FROM Employers AS emp 
WHERE (SELECT SUM(Amount) AS summAmount FROM Payments AS pay 
       WHERE pay.employer_id = emp.id) >= 3000
```

Comment: а структуру таблиц можно?

Comment: Вот.


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Employers` (
 `Id` int(2) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;


INSERT INTO `Employers` (`Id`, `Name`) VALUES
(1, 'Vasya'),
(2, 'Krivetkin');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Payments` (
 `Employer_ID` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `Amount` int(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `Payments` (`Employer_ID`, `Amount`) VALUES
(1, 2800),
(1, 222),
(2, 290),
(2, 120);

Это для примера или лучше вот: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/065d9/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select emp.id, emp.name from Employers as emp
left join payments as pay on pay.employer_id = emp.id
group by pay.employer_id
having sum(pay.amount)>=3000
;
```

Маны - ну, собственно по join, having, group by, аггрегирующим функциям.